# What is the JVM memory allocated by default

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

In my `Catalina.bat` file

```
:doStop
shift
set ACTION=stop
set CATALINA_OPTS=
goto execCmd
```

`Xms` has not specified , so what would be the memory allocated by default ??

is there any specific command to check the allocation given to the jvm ?

Answer (score 1):

Java will choose default values depending on the actual environment, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html. To see actual memory options run java with -XX:printCommandLineFlags. Another option is to run jconsole util, connect to running Java app and go to "VM Summary" tab.

Comment: Java is supposed to behave the same way on all supported platforms